# Ossec nothing returned error

Tags: security, ubuntu, intrusion-detection

When searching in the Ossec server for the report, it is showing **nothing returned (or search expired).** What's this error?

Answer (score 1):

/var/log/apache2/error.log showed that a tmp directory was missing in the Ossec root directory

```
fopen(./tmp/output-tmp.1-121-740837e5692760ab1b2d8337c56a7132.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/ossec-wui-0.9/lib/os_lib_alerts.php on line 39
```

Created a tmp directory in /var/www/ossec-wui-0.9

Changed ownership to www-data

Restarted apache

Issue Fixed. Search results showing now.